# How to verify whether validation message is displaying or not using protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Test case : I just want to validate the "Name" field by sending "alpha numeric characters" data one at a time into the name field and verify whether "invalid data" validation message is displaying or not

My Spec file code is below.

```
   //Testcase 3 : To verify whether "Name" field validation message is displaying or not 
// "name field is a required" field
using(CertificationTestData.testData, function(testdata){

    it('validation of Certificate Name field content',()=>{

        //To clear the "Ceritication Name" field data
        page.getCertificationNameField().clear();

        //enter each type of test data one at a time
        page.getCertificationNameField().sendKeys(testdata.data);

        browser.driver.sleep(5000);

        page.getAnyWhereCertificationPage().click();         

        //To check whether any validation message is displaying for "Name" field
        expect(page.getValidationMessage().isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

My external test data file is below

```
 testData :[
    {data:"abcd"},
    {data: "1234"},
    {data:"!@#$%#"},
    {data:"ad123!@##$"}
],
```

My Po file code is below.

```
 //To return "Certification Name" field 
getCertificationNameField(){
    return element(by.css('input[formcontrolname="CertificationsName"]'));
}


 //To return validation message 
getValidationMessage(){
    return element(by.className('ui-message ui-messages-error ui-corner-all'));
}
```

When i run my test script it is displaying below error message.

```
 should test certificate tab validation of Certificate Name field content
```

- Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .ui-message.ui-messages-error.ui-corner-all)

Is there any way to verify whether the validation message is displaying or not ??

Answer (score 0):

`isDisplayed()` always requires the presence of the element as it executes the ElementFinder and returns the error of it.

If the element is for sure displayed, when it's present, just replace `isDisplayed()` with `isPresent()`.

Else check `if(element.isPresent()){expect(element.isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy()} else {expect(element.isPresent()).toBeFalsy()}` ... though it's a bit strange and verbose that way.